# Setting Global MIME types in w2k3

Tags: iis, types, mime

When setting MIME types in IIS 6.0 I understand that to set them globally I right click on Web Sites / Properties.  This is useful if I have a clean server as each new website I create then inherits these properties.

Issue I have currently is I have a server with 200 existing web sites.  If I add a global MIME type I am given two inheritence popups (one for UNC password and one for MIME types).  If I select any of these and click OK my global MIME types override any custom MIME types I have set.

Shorter question:  I need to add new MIME types that apply to all existing sites under IIS 6.0 **without** over writing or removing any existing custom MIME types individual sites may already have set.  Is there any way to do this?